# Chess Board Problems

Tags: c, chess

*There is a chess board of dimension `n * n`. You are given with 2 squares on that board `S(x1,y1)` ;`M(x2,y2)`. `S` is a fixed point. `M` can move diagonally. It can move any number of steps or jumps in 1 move . Find the minimum number of moves `M` needs to reach `S`*

**My Approach:** We can just count diagonal blocks, But I'm confused with jumps. Can anybody explain what they meant by jumps?

Comment: Why would we know that? It sounds like a made-up term for an assignment. I don't think there is any such thing as an official description of what a "jump" is

Comment: Also what if S(x1, y1) is on a white square and M(x2, y2) is on a black square. You can't get there with diagonal movements, what does the problem description say about that

Comment: Best guess is that a step is move of one square, e.g. from (1,1) to (2,2). A jump is a move of more than one square in a single direction, e.g. from (1,1) to (5,5).

Comment: Another guess-> If there is already a chess piece on the diagonal way that S is supposed to be taking, it might *jump* over it and go one (or more) cells (diagonally) past it!

Comment: I like HappyCoder's guess, since the problem isn't very interesting unless there are obstacles on the board. Perhaps you can jump over obstacles but not stop on the same square as an obstacle. In any event, you should be asking your professor, or a teacher's assistant, or your classmates.

Comment: Yes as @HappyCoder said and in que as mentioned **no. of steps or jumps in one move** so it may jump over pieces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think jump here refers to the case when the chess the piece can move diagonally more than 1 step. Example if at (1,1) then it can go to (3,3) in a single step.

I have coded a bactracking algorithm assuming the above case.
The basic idea here to get all possible moves to reach the destination (x,y) co-ordinate. It checks all valid moves at a given position and prints the path followed to reach here. `construct_candidates()` will give you all valid candidate co-ordinates for the current position. It checks the bounds and also validates we have not visited the chess block earlier, if these conditions are satisfied, then it is a valid candidate for the move.

You can easily modify it to keep track of the shortest possible path followed.

```
#define N 4 /* Chess Board Dimension */
#define TRUE     1   
#define FALSE    0

#define START_X  0
#define START_Y  0
#define TARGET_X 1
#define TARGET_Y 3

typedef short int bool;

typedef struct point_ {
    int x;
    int y;
} point_t;


bool is_candidate_valid (point_t *a, int k, int new_x, int new_y)
{
    int i;
    /* Check bounds */
    if ((new_x < 0) || (new_x > (N-1)) ||
        (new_y < 0) || (new_y > (N-1))) {
        return FALSE;
    }

    /* Check if this new position is already in the path followed */

    for (i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        if (a[i].x == new_x && a[i].y == new_y) {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
    return TRUE;
}

void construct_candidates (point_t *a, int k, point_t *candidates, int *n_candidates)
{
    int delta;
    *n_candidates = 0;
    int new_x, new_y;

    for (delta = 1; delta <= (N-1); delta++)  {

        new_x = a[k-1].x + delta;
        new_y = a[k-1].y + delta;

        if (is_candidate_valid (a, k, new_x, new_y) == TRUE) {
             candidates[*n_candidates].x = new_x;
             candidates[*n_candidates].y = new_y;
             (*n_candidates)++;
        }

        new_x = a[k-1].x + delta;
        new_y = a[k-1].y - delta;

        if (is_candidate_valid (a, k, new_x, new_y) == TRUE) {
             candidates[*n_candidates].x = new_x;
             candidates[*n_candidates].y = new_y;
             (*n_candidates)++;
        }

        new_x = a[k-1].x - delta;
        new_y = a[k-1].y + delta;

        if (is_candidate_valid (a, k, new_x, new_y) == TRUE) {
             candidates[*n_candidates].x = new_x;
             candidates[*n_candidates].y = new_y;
             (*n_candidates)++;
        }

        new_x = a[k-1].x - delta;
        new_y = a[k-1].y - delta;

        if (is_candidate_valid (a, k, new_x, new_y) == TRUE) {
             candidates[*n_candidates].x = new_x;
             candidates[*n_candidates].y = new_y;
             (*n_candidates)++;
        }
    }
}

bool is_a_solution (point_t *a, int k)
{
    if (a[k-1].x == TARGET_X && a[k-1].y == TARGET_Y) {
        return TRUE; /* Actual Solution found */
    }
    if (k == (N*N)) {
        return TRUE; /* No Solution found */
    }
    return FALSE;
}

void process_solution (point_t *a, int k)
{
    int i;

    if (k == (N*N)) {
        return; /* No solution Possible */
    }

    for (i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        printf ("(%d, %d) ", a[i].x, a[i].y);
    }
    printf ("\n");
}


void backtrack (point_t *a, int k)
{
    int i, n_candidates;
    point_t candidates[4*(N-1)];

    if (is_a_solution (a, k) == TRUE) {
        process_solution (a, k);
        return;
    }

    construct_candidates (a, k, candidates, &n_candidates);
    for (i = 0; i < n_candidates; i++) {
        a[k].x = candidates[i].x;
        a[k].y = candidates[i].y;

        backtrack (a, k + 1);
    }
}

int main()
{
    point_t a[N*N];
    /* Fill up the initial position */
    a[0].x = START_X;
    a[0].y = START_Y;

    backtrack (a, 1);
}
```

> ```
> Output:   
>
> (0, 0) (1, 1) (2, 2) (3, 1) (2, 0) (0, 2) (1, 3) 
> (0, 0) (1, 1) (2, 2) (3, 1) (1, 3) 
> (0, 0) (1, 1) (2, 2) (1, 3) 
> (0, 0) (1, 1) (2, 0) (3, 1) (2, 2) (1, 3) 
> (0, 0) (1, 1) (2, 0) (3, 1) (1, 3) 
> (0, 0) (1, 1) (2, 0) (0, 2) (1, 3) 
> (0, 0) (1, 1) (0, 2) (1, 3) 
> (0, 0) (1, 1) (0, 2) (2, 0) (3, 1) (2, 2) (1, 3) 
> (0, 0) (1, 1) (0, 2) (2, 0) (3, 1) (1, 3) 
> (0, 0) (1, 1) (3, 3) (2, 2) (3, 1) (2, 0) (0, 2) (1, 3) 
> (0, 0) (1, 1) (3, 3) (2, 2) (3, 1) (1, 3) 
> (0, 0) (1, 1) (3, 3) (2, 2) (1, 3) 
> (0, 0) (2, 2) (3, 3) (1, 1) (2, 0) (3, 1) (1, 3) 
> (0, 0) (2, 2) (3, 3) (1, 1) (2, 0) (0, 2) (1, 3) 
> (0, 0) (2, 2) (3, 3) (1, 1) (0, 2) (1, 3) 
> (0, 0) (2, 2) (3, 3) (1, 1) (0, 2) (2, 0) (3, 1) (1, 3) 
> (0, 0) (2, 2) (3, 1) (2, 0) (1, 1) (0, 2) (1, 3) 
> (0, 0) (2, 2) (3, 1) (2, 0) (0, 2) (1, 3) 
> (0, 0) (2, 2) (3, 1) (1, 3) 
> (0, 0) (2, 2) (1, 3) 
> (0, 0) (2, 2) (1, 1) (2, 0) (3, 1) (1, 3) 
> (0, 0) (2, 2) (1, 1) (2, 0) (0, 2) (1, 3) 
> (0, 0) (2, 2) (1, 1) (0, 2) (1, 3) 
> (0, 0) (2, 2) (1, 1) (0, 2) (2, 0) (3, 1) (1, 3) 
> (0, 0) (3, 3) (2, 2) (3, 1) (2, 0) (1, 1) (0, 2) (1, 3) 
> (0, 0) (3, 3) (2, 2) (3, 1) (2, 0) (0, 2) (1, 3) 
> (0, 0) (3, 3) (2, 2) (3, 1) (1, 3) 
> (0, 0) (3, 3) (2, 2) (1, 3) 
> (0, 0) (3, 3) (2, 2) (1, 1) (2, 0) (3, 1) (1, 3) 
> (0, 0) (3, 3) (2, 2) (1, 1) (2, 0) (0, 2) (1, 3) 
> (0, 0) (3, 3) (2, 2) (1, 1) (0, 2) (1, 3) 
> (0, 0) (3, 3) (2, 2) (1, 1) (0, 2) (2, 0) (3, 1) (1, 3) 
> (0, 0) (3, 3) (1, 1) (2, 2) (3, 1) (2, 0) (0, 2) (1, 3) 
> (0, 0) (3, 3) (1, 1) (2, 2) (3, 1) (1, 3) 
> (0, 0) (3, 3) (1, 1) (2, 2) (1, 3) 
> (0, 0) (3, 3) (1, 1) (2, 0) (3, 1) (2, 2) (1, 3) 
> (0, 0) (3, 3) (1, 1) (2, 0) (3, 1) (1, 3) 
> (0, 0) (3, 3) (1, 1) (2, 0) (0, 2) (1, 3) 
> (0, 0) (3, 3) (1, 1) (0, 2) (1, 3) 
> (0, 0) (3, 3) (1, 1) (0, 2) (2, 0) (3, 1) (2, 2) (1, 3) 
> (0, 0) (3, 3) (1, 1) (0, 2) (2, 0) (3, 1) (1, 3)
> ```

Comment: That's a lot of code to solve the problem with no obstacles. But it did find the correct answer: (0,0) (2,2) (1,3).

Comment: I have explicitly divided the code among functions to improve readability. It is not not that long ~130 odd lines.